# List only files and not directories in archive

Tags: files, filenames, zip, archive, gunzip

I have a zip achieve like below

```
$ unzip -l 5124.zip
Archive:  5124.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  01-13-2021 09:22   u/
        0  01-13-2021 09:22   u/MyCom/
        0  01-13-2021 09:22   u/MyCom/UNX/
        0  01-13-2021 09:22   u/MyCom/UNX/scripts/
        0  01-13-2021 09:22   u/MyCom/UNX/scripts/SYNC/
        0  01-13-2021 09:22   u/MyCom/UNX/scripts/SYNC/sql/
    48704  01-13-2021 01:50   u/MyCom/UNX/scripts/SYNC/sql/Load.sql
    41872  01-13-2021 01:00   u/MyCom/UNX/scripts/SYNC/sql/Update1.sql
---------                     -------
    90576                     8 files
```

I want to just get the filenames in the archive while ignoring the rest which in the above case is

```
/u/MyCom/UNX/scripts/SYNC/sql/Load.sql
/u/MyCom/UNX/scripts/SYNC/sql/Update1.sql
```

Note: The preceding `/` is missing from the output of `unzip` this I need

```
/u/MyCom/UNX/scripts/SYNC/sql/Load.sql
/u/MyCom/UNX/scripts/SYNC/sql/Update1.sql
```

and not

```
u/MyCom/UNX/scripts/SYNC/sql/Load.sql
u/MyCom/UNX/scripts/SYNC/sql/Update1.sql
```

Any good way to get this info from any given zip ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `zipinfo -1` to list the file paths and `sed` to remove the paths ending with a `/` and to
prefix each line with a `/`:

```
$ zipinfo -1 5124.zip | sed '/\/$/d;s/^/\//'
/u/MyCom/UNX/scripts/SYNC/sql/Load.sql
/u/MyCom/UNX/scripts/SYNC/sql/Update1.sql
```

Comment: works Amazing !! Thank you @Freddy for the solution.